# when I try and set the Shipping Profile to eBay Trading API, AddFixedPriceItem call it still requires a Shipping Method?

Tags: xml, filemaker, ebay-api

Ok so I am using the [eBay Trading API](https://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/AddFixedPriceItem.html) in Filemaker Pro and my issue is: I am wanting to be able to add items to eBay and use our defined company shipping profile. The issue is When I was doing this it was giving me a response:

```
<LongMessage>At least one valid shipping service must be specified.</LongMessage>
```

What is the point of telling it your shipping profile:

```
"<SellerProfiles>" &
"<SellerPaymentProfile>" &
"<PaymentProfileID>" & $Payment_Policy_ID & "</PaymentProfileID>" &
"<PaymentProfileName>Standard Payment (JakeSales)</PaymentProfileName>" &
"</SellerPaymentProfile>" &
"<SellerReturnProfile>" &
"<ReturnProfileID>" & $Return_Policy_ID & "</ReturnProfileID>" &
"<ReturnProfileName>Returns Accepted,Buyer,30 Days,Money Back,DeductOUTshipping</ReturnProfileName>" &
"</SellerReturnProfile>" &
"<SellerShippingProfile>" &
"<ShippingProfileID>" & $Shipping_Policy_ID & "</ShippingProfileID>" &
"<ShippingProfileName>Shipping Policy (FirstClass w/Global Prg)</ShippingProfileName>" &
"</SellerShippingProfile>" &
"</SellerProfiles>"
```

If you then have to define a shipping service? which is defined in your shipping profile? so then I had to add:

```
/*Here in lies the issue. ebay requires you to have the codes for each service you want to be able to ship.
https://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/types/ShippingServiceCodeType.html
the address above will require us to make our list of shipping options available and also have the ebay specific title such as "USPSPriorityFlatRateEnvelope" even having the shipping profile preset doesn't work.*/
"<ShippingDetails>" &
"<ShippingServiceOptions>" & 
"<FreeShipping>0</FreeShipping>" & 
"<ShippingService>USPSPriorityFlatRateEnvelope</ShippingService>" & 
"<ShippingServiceCost>8.45</ShippingServiceCost>" & 
"<ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>" & 
"</ShippingServiceOptions>" &
"</ShippingDetails>"
```

Now I have to go into the listing, everything is correct but I then have to change the shipping service to the profile which is already correct. Does anyone have a solution to this? I tried just sending the shipping profile, but it wants a shipping service. Their samples are not very helpful as the sample is for a car listing. which obviously does not have shipping on the listing. Thanks for the help peeps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but I'm answering from mobile..

Try Adding only `Payment/Shipping/ReturnProfileID` and not `ProfileName`
But first you have to create the profiles on eBay website: I'm not fully sure but I think the related APIs have been decommissioned last year. You can avoid to set `ShippingDetails` since profiles are required and have precedence.

Beside this, several Trading APIs have been decommissioned in the last 12 months and most new features are only supported by new `REST APIs`: you should evaluate to use such.

Comment: fair enough, I will give that a try, Boss doesn't want to ust the Rest as he said last time he had used it it took twice as many calls to actually edit a product we have listed. So until he changes his mind we have to make these ones work Lol. thanks.